# React typescript: eslint max-length autofix does not work

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am trying setup React typescript's eslint setup where code's max lenght is 80, if the code is more than 80 then it will break the line and codes will go to the next line automatically. But seems like my eslint max-lenght auto-fix does not work. I just go warn and when i click the quick its just disable the entire component. Currently, my code looks this, I have scroll all the way to the right to see all the codes. PS. I delete prettier extension.

[image]

**This is my .eslintrc.js setup**

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    jsx: true,
    useJSXTextNode: true
  },
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
    "react",
    "react-hooks"
  ],
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: "999.999.999" // no latest option, 999.999.999 as a hack
    }
  },
  rules: {
    semi: ["warn", "always"],
    indent: "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": ["warn", 2],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": 0,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "quotes": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": ["warn", "backtick", { avoidEscape: true }],
    "max-len": ["warn", { code: 80, ignoreComments: true }],
    "arrow-parens": ["warn", "always"],
    "arrow-spacing": "warn",
    "no-var": "warn",
    "no-const-assign": "warn",
    "no-dupe-class-members": "warn",
    "no-duplicate-imports": ["warn", { includeExports: true }],
    "prefer-arrow-callback": ["warn", { "allowNamedFunctions": true }],
    "prefer-const": "warn",
    "react/display-name": ["warn", { "ignoreTranspilerName": true }],
    "padding-line-between-statements": [
      "warn",
      { blankLine: "always", prev: "function", next: "function" }
    ],
    "prefer-destructuring": [
      "warn",
      {
        array: false,
        object: true
      },
      {
        enforceForRenamedProperties: false
      }
    ],
    "template-curly-spacing": "warn",
    "no-dupe-args": "warn",
    "no-dupe-keys": "warn",
    "no-duplicate-case": "warn",
    "no-empty": "warn",
    "no-extra-semi": "warn",
    "no-extra-parens": ["warn", "all"],
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": "warn",
    "no-func-assign": "warn",
    "no-inner-declarations": "warn",
    "no-irregular-whitespace": "warn",
    "no-sparse-arrays": "warn",
    "no-unreachable": "warn",
    "accessor-pairs": "warn",
    "block-scoped-var": "warn",
    curly: "warn",
    "default-case": "warn",
    "dot-notation": "warn",
    eqeqeq: "warn",
    "guard-for-in": "warn",
    "no-empty-pattern": "warn",
    "no-multi-spaces": ["warn", { ignoreEOLComments: true }],
    "no-new": "warn",
    "no-new-func": "warn",
    "array-bracket-newline": ["warn", { multiline: true }],
    "array-bracket-spacing": ["warn", "never"],
    "block-spacing": "warn",
    "brace-style": ["warn", "1tbs", { allowSingleLine: true }],
    camelcase: "warn",
    "comma-dangle": [
      "warn",
      {
        arrays: "never",
        objects: "never",
        imports: "never",
        exports: "never",
        functions: "never"
      }
    ],
    "comma-spacing": ["warn", { before: false, after: true }],
    "comma-style": ["warn", "last"],
    "computed-property-spacing": ["warn", "never"],
    "eol-last": ["warn", "always"],
    "func-call-spacing": ["warn", "never"],
    "func-names": ["warn", "always", { "generators": "as-needed" }],
    "func-style": ["warn", "expression", { allowArrowFunctions: true }],
    "jsx-quotes": ["warn", "prefer-double"],
    "key-spacing": ["warn", { beforeColon: false }],
    "keyword-spacing": ["warn", { before: true }],
    "lines-around-comment": ["warn", { beforeBlockComment: false }],
    "no-array-constructor": "warn",
    "no-lonely-if": "warn",
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["warn", { max: 1, maxEOF: 1 }],
    "no-multi-assign": "warn",
    "no-trailing-spaces": "warn",
    "no-unneeded-ternary": "warn",
    "no-whitespace-before-property": "warn",
    "object-curly-spacing": ["warn", "always"],
    "object-property-newline": ["warn", { allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine: true }],
    "padded-blocks": ["warn", "never"],
    "quote-props": ["warn", "always"],
    "semi-spacing": ["warn", { before: false, after: true }],
    "semi-style": ["warn", "last"],
    "sort-vars": ["warn", { ignoreCase: true }],
    "space-before-blocks": ["warn", "always"],
    "space-before-function-paren": ["warn", {
      "anonymous": "never",
      "named": "never",
      "asyncArrow": "always"
    }],
    "space-in-parens": ["warn", "never"],
    "spaced-comment": ["warn", "always"],
    "switch-colon-spacing": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": "warn",
    "no-empty-function": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": ["error", { "allow": ["arrowFunctions"] }],
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
  }
};
```

** This is my .vscode/settings.json **

```
{
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "blink",
    "editor.cursorStyle": "line",
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Operator Mono',  'SF Mono', Menlo, Operator Mono, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.fontWeight": "500",
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.letterSpacing": 0,
    "editor.lineHeight": 28,
    "editor.lineNumbers": "on",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "comments": false,
        "other": true,
        "strings": false
    },
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,
    "editor.renderControlCharacters": true,
    "editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "editor.rulers": [
        90,
        100
    ],
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.trimAutoWhitespace": true,
    "files.autoGuessEncoding": true,
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "files.defaultLanguage": "html",
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.pyc": true,
        "**/package-lock.json": true,
        "**/styles/css/": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.hg": true,
        "**/.svn": true,
        "**/CVS": true,
        "**/distribution/": true,
        "**/dist/": true,
        "**/libraries/": true,
        "**/lib/": true,
        "**/node_modules/": true,
        "**/build/": true,
    },
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vs-seti",
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    "editor.dragAndDrop": false,
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.vue": "html",
        "Vagrantfile": "ruby",
        "*.js": "javascript"
    },
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": false,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=100",
    ],
    "python.linting.pycodestyleArgs": [
        "--ignore=E501"
    ],
    "[plaintext]": {},
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    },
    "[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    },
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
    },
    "typescript.validate.enable": false,
    "javascript.validate.enable": false,
    "docthis.includeDescriptionTag": true,
    "docthis.inferTypesFromNames": true,
    "merge-conflict.autoNavigateNextConflict.enabled": true,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "typescript.surveys.enabled": false,
    "eslint.validate": [

      { "language": "javascript", "autoFix": true },
      { "language": "javascriptreact", "autoFix": true },
      { "language": "typescript", "autoFix": true },
      { "language": "typescriptreact", "autoFix": true }
    ],
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Night Owl",
    "workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
    "eslint.codeAction.disableRuleComment": {},
    "eslint.codeAction.showDocumentation": {}
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There have been a couple of [issues](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11325) that are opened, about adding auto-fix for the `max-len` rule, but unfortunately, the eslint team doesn't seem willing to pursue it (the reasons are stated on the thread).

You can consider disabling that rule for the particular line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
```

If you are looking for an auto-fix solution, I would recommend you to re-install prettier.

Answer (score 10):

> NOTE: The below answer does not exactly address the question. The question is about eslint specifically, and this solution is for prettier, a different formatting library that can work alongside eslint.

In my case I had an error in my eslintrc.json (an extra comma in the end) and so no lint configuration was being picked up.

Fixing that solved my problem.

Also, make sure you're using prettier as a dependency and NOT  as an extension on VScode.

prettier.config.json

```
module.exports = {
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
  printWidth: 80,
  bracketSpacing: true,
  jsxBracketSameLine: true,
};
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-hooks",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      },
      {
        "usePrettierrc": true
      }
    ],
    "import/no-dynamic-require":"off",
    "global-require": "off",
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "import/no-cycle": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
    "import/no-named-as-default": "off",
    "import/no-named-as-default-member": "off",
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "radix": "off",
    "import/order": "off",
    "no-plusplus": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "no-unused-expressions": "off",
    "array-callback-return": "warn",
    "react/jsx-no-bind": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "consistent-return": "off",
    "new-cap": "off",
    "react/destructuring-assignment": "off",
    "react/forbid-prop-types": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "react/no-unused-state": "warn",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "no-nested-ternary": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": "off",
    "react/sort-comp": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off",
    "no-return-assign": "warn",
    "react/no-array-index-key": "warn",
    "guard-for-in": "warn",
    "no-restricted-syntax": "warn",
    "max-classes-per-file": "off",
    "react/state-in-constructor": "off",
    "react/static-property-placement": "off",
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": "off",
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": "warn",
    "camelcase": "off",
    "prefer-destructuring": "warn",
    "no-await-in-loop": "warn",
    "no-restricted-globals": "off",
    "no-bitwise": "off",
    "eqeqeq": "warn",
    "no-shadow": "warn",
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": "off",
    "react/button-has-type": "off"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  }
```

Comment: so eslint autofix for max-len works for you?

Comment: Can you share your eslintrc.json file? For me it does not work

Comment: Sorry, man. Been away for a while. I'm actually not using max-len, but prettier printWidth. I'll update my answer with the files.

Comment: Looks like they're using prettier, which is a different formatting library which does support fixing stuff like line length. I've used it to autoformat in the precommit git hook and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution to this issue you can use both pretiier and eslint, that's what I do and it works fine

Comment: There's literally no point to doing that when eslint both pretties your code, and enforces constraints, prettier does not.